# android send utf8 content to servlet

Tags: java, android, hibernate, servlets, web

I'm using Android to send English and Arabic content to Servlet but the data goes to the server with. How to solve it ? here is my code in Android:

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(gsonString);
se.setContentType("text/json;charset=UTF-8");
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(methodURL);
httpRequest.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest,localContext);
```

Servlet code

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
    String line = in.readLine();
    String gsonString = line;
    while (line != null) {
        gsonString += line;
        line = in.readLine();
    }
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried to create StringEntity with UTF8 format, I mean something like this in your code:
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(gsonString, "UTF-8");

Comment: why are you setting the character encoding to  `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-16");` try `UTF-8`

Comment: about StringEntity se = new StringEntity(gsonString, "UTF-8"); the same issue the server got ????? about UTF-16 i tried before to insert utf-8 the data base got ???? then i used utf-16 it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

Gson gson = new Gson();
        String gsonString = gson.toJson(currentCustomer);
        Log.v("gson", gsonString);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(currentCustomer),
                "UTF-8");
HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(methodURL);
        httpRequest.setHeader("customerRegisrationData", gsonString);
        httpRequest.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest,
                localContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use these methods

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(method_url);

StringEntity postEntity = new StringEntity(HTTP.UTF_8);
httpPost.setEntity(postEntity)
```

OR

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postData));
```

Comment: StringEntity postEntity = new StringEntity(HTTP.UTF_8);
httpPost.setEntity(postEntity);    how to put the data in this stringEntity ???

Comment: i don't know if it is right or not i don't know how to write the data in this entity